# How to maintain my collections while upgrading from Solr 4.0 to 4.8?

Tags: solr, upgrade

I'm using Solr 4.0 and have two rather large collections indexed.  I would rather not have to reload the data when upgrading to 4.8, but I'm not finding much in the way of instructions on how to maintain my collections.  Is there a procedure for this other than common sense?

Comment: Can you try installing 4.8 and then copying the indexes over without disturbing your current instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are compatible.  Upgrade your Solr and point the new version at the same index location and everything just works.